# Update plots during for loop from within Rstudio?

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plotting during a loop in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772630/plotting-during-a-loop-in-rstudio)

I'm trying to monitor the status of a convergence loop, and I can't seem to get it to update the graph each time it iterates.

Here's some sample code:

```
print(plot(c(0,1)~c(0,100)))
for(i in seq(100)) {
  Sys.sleep(.1)
  print(points( runif(1)~i ))
}
```

Note that the graph only updates *after* everything's been plotted.  I need it to update each loop iteration.  I thought `print` would do that, but it's not working.

**Update**

This is an RStudio-specific problem, as it works properly in base R.  Is there a way to force graphing in RStudio each loop iteration?

Comment: On second thought, this is clearly an RStudio problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have to ever print base graphics things to get them to display anyway.

Comment: @Spacedman Yeah I guess that's only grid-based graphics that need it.  Still, I was hoping it would force RStudio's hand.  Clearly not.

Comment: Have you tried `dev.flush()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772630/plotting-during-a-loop-in-rstudioI have asked this question before, here are the solutions:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start up a separate graphics device with `X11()` (or `win()` on windows?) and use that.

Although plots seem to update okay on my RStudio setup. My test is simply:

```
plot(1:10);for(i in 1:10){points(10-i,i);Sys.sleep(1)}
```

I see the first set of 10 points, then the next set appear at one second intervals, in the RStudio embedded graphics window.

Comment: That appears to work...except on RStudio Server, where one cannot launch new Xorg windows.

Comment: Well, maybe the RStudio staff on their support site where you cross-posted this will help you! http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/3729-graph-does-not-update-until-loop-completion

Comment: People get their panties in such a knot over cross-posting...

Comment: Yeah I didn't quite think of it as cross-posting, as I forgot it's public rather than just a support request.  Sorry.

Comment: @user1717913  :   "You must be new here."   Or, if you prefer,  "omg Canter and Siegal"

Comment: Now I don't know where to post my 'it works for me' answer - here, on RStudio help, or in the chat. Or all three.

Comment: RStudio staff suggest `Sys.sleep(0)` to force an update, which works for me for the first few iterations but not subsequent ones.