# Binwidth for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

This works

```
for (i in 1:50) {
    plot(1,i)
}
```

This does not work, why? it is **binwidth** I want to have changing

```
d <- diamonds
for (i in 1:50 by=10) {
ggplot(aes(x = d$price), data = d) + geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = '#099DD1', binwidth = i)
}
```

Comment: when using ggplot, don't assign aesthetics using the `$` extractor. Just use the variable name, as the scope is already evaluated in the data frame environment.  Just ggplot(d, aes(x=price))+ geom_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a loop? You could try this instead:

```
 lapply(seq(1,50,10), function(x) ggplot(aes(x = d$price), data = d) + geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = '#099DD1', binwidth = x))
```

Comment: does not have to be a loop.

Answer (score 1):

plotting in a loop (or through `source`) has some unexpected pitfalls ([Plotting during a loop in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772630/plotting-during-a-loop-in-rstudio), [R: ggplot does not work if it is inside a for loop although it works outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678261/r-ggplot-does-not-work-if-it-is-inside-a-for-loop-although-it-works-outside-of)) so here it helps to enclose it in a `print()`. Also notice that you should use `seq(from, to, by)` as below:

```
d <- diamonds
for (i in seq(1,50,10)) {
  print(ggplot(aes(x = d$price), data = d) + geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = '#099DD1', binwidth = i))
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @limonte, could you please specify? in my opinion the code provided above gives the desired output (as far as I understand the question) and is easy enough to compare to the original code to serve as answer.

Comment: @limonte I added some explanation upon your suggestion, thanks for clarifying. However I think the code itself is self-explanatory to who has read the question and answer and taken two minutes to compare the two. Just my opinion. It seems an interesting question to ask on meta as what can be considered a minimal answer.